# How to type-cast contract type to address type?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, addresses, type-casting

**Contracts can be explicitly converted to and from the address type.**
In solidity docs, it's mentioned that the contracts can be converted into an address type. But when I try to do so the compiler gives me the following error. **Explicit type conversion not allowed from "type(contract)" to "address"**

What I'm exactly trying to do is the following

```
contract A {
    // some logic 
}

contract B {
    //some logic
}

contract C{
    address a = address(A);
    address b = address(B);
}
```

The error I'm getting:-

> Explicit type conversion not allowed from "type(contract A)" to "address". address a = address(A);

> Explicit type conversion not allowed from "type(contract B)" to "address". address b = address(B);

[This](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/types.html#index-6) is the link for the doc where I saw this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create these contracts in order to get their address, change this:

```
contract C {
    address a = address(A);
    address b = address(B);
}
```

To this:

```
contract C {
    address a = address(new A());
    address b = address(new B());
}
```

Then you can read them like this:

```
function getContractAddresses() view public returns(address, address) {
    return (a, b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. If I'm not wrong the address a would not be equal to the address of contract A? I want the address of contract A to be stored in the variable address a.

Comment: You're wrong, just debug what I've sent you. By just leaving multiple contracts in one .sol file this does not mean that you are deploying them. In my example when you're deploying ```contract C``` ( manually ) then once it is deployed, that particular contract is also deploying contracts ```A``` and ```B```.